# MySQLi module for PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I’m trying to install an open source classifieds program with the following Installation requirements:

- PHP version: 5.x or newer
- MySQL database (or access to create one)
- MySQLi module for PHP
- GD module for PHP

I’m using XAMPP, 1.7.7 [PHP: 5.3.8] on windows 7.

When I execute the installation script by accessing `index.php` (as instructed), I receive the following error message:

Warning: `mysqli::close() [mysqli.close]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\oc-includes\classes\database\DBConnectionClass.php on line 530`

Note: The above platform that I use, executes fluently other codes written in PHP, MySQL etc’.

I couldn’t find any information on the above from Xampp or from the script’s publisher.
My question is how to open MySQLi module for PHP, if it’s not open by default?

Comment: are you sure you have set your configuration as correct?

Comment: yes, I’m sure, configuration is correct.

Comment: the error message is not complaining about the library installation; the function is being called successfully. It's hard to be sure without seeing any code at all, but my guess is that you're not passing a valid database handle to the mysqli_close() call.

Comment: Have you checked the output of phpinfo() to see that mysqli is there?

Comment: @Spudley, thanks - how can I make sure that MySQLi module for PHP is enable because  I’m getting similar error message also on my remote server.

Comment: @Mark Baker, the following is the output “MysqlI Support enabled”:
Client API library version: mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev
Active Persistent Links:0 
Inactive Persistent Links:0 
Active Links:0